# Connecting 2 conatiners with docker --network

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-network

I am trying to connect a phpmyadmin container to another mysql container. I have created a network with `docker network create` and added my two containers. But when I tried to login with phpmyadmin, the **password is incorrect** error displayed each time.
I checked that the two containers are available to my networks which I already created so I tried to `ping` mysql container to phpmyadmin container but unfortunately I had negative results.
I followed this tutorial:

https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/docker/docker-networking-example/

Can you explain to me how the commend `docker run --network` works exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is ok, so you can `ping` one container from another using container name. When you create a network between 2 containers, it creates an alias with the container name and the container IP.
For instance

```
docker network create my-bridge-network
docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -d mysql/mysql-server --network my-bridge-network
docker run --name phpmyadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=mysql -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin --network my-bridge-network
```

In this case when you `exec` `ping` from `phpmyadmin` container you should be able to ping `mysql` container

```
docker exec phpmyadmin ping mysql # if in phpmyadmin `ping` program is available
```

Comment: Thank you for this informtaion. I tried exec ping from phpmyadmin and i succeeded but when i tried with mysql the ping failed. My question is : should i use the image mysql/mysql-server or i can do it with any dabtabse server

Comment: If you specify docker network, it connects containers. So containers would be able to communicate with each other. Therefore you can specify any database server in other container and if there are in the same network you can ping them inside the containers